# programa que solicite una cantidad de numeros y luego lo muestre separados

Tags: python

Hola soy bastante nuevo en el tema de la programación,y quiero crear un programa que haga lo siguiente

el usuario pondrá cierta cantidad de números por ejemplo : 203408908 . y quiero que después le muestre al usuario el mismo numero que el puso pero así : 20.340.890-8

intente colocando

```
print(".".join(el nombre del dato))
```

pero me sale así

```
2.0.3.4.0.8.9.0.8
```

luego intente separando el ultimo digito

```
R = input("ingrese su rut ; ") d = input("ingrese su dv : ")
# Rut = XX.XXX.XXX

print(".".join(R), "-".join(d))
```

pero me salio asi:

```
2.0.3.4.0.8.9.0 8
```

no quiero que me den la respuesta en si. solo como podría llegar al resultado final , alguna ayuda o algo similar , algún comando en especifico

Comment: Bienvenido, te comento que deberías leer [ask], una vez hecho lo anterior te invito a que trates algo y cuando tengas dudas puntuales sobre una base de código demostrable edites la pregunta e indiques donde tienes dudas

Comment: podrias  explicar el formato

Comment: Ya supe como resolverlo .. era mas sencillo de lo que me imagine era      R = input("ingrese su rut ; ")                                                                               print(R[0:2],".",R[2:5],".",R[5:8],"-",R[8] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar los separadores de miles y decimales y reemplazarlos por los valores esperados.

```
i = 203408908

print ("{:,.1f}".format(i/10)).replace(".", "-").replace(",", ".")
# 20.340.890-8
```

La division por 10 permite separar el ultimo dígito.

Comment: y los rut -k ???
se debe manejar como string, no como númerico

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7+ o 3+

Con [string.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) puedes usar `{0:,}` para separar con `,` y despues, cambiar `,` por `.`.

Mire  [Format Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax): *Using the comma as a thousands separator*

```
print('{0:,}'.format(123456789).replace(',', '.'))
```

Output: `123.456.789`